# Error in SQL syntax and I'm not seeing it

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have an error in my query. Here is the query:

```
select HourTime, count(*) from
(
select substring(time,1,2) as HourTime, count(*) as ActivityCount
from htmp_cs368 a
group by HourTime
)htmp
union
(
select substring(time,1,2) as HourTime, count(*) as ActivityCount
from atmp_cs368 a
group by HourTime
)atmp
group by HourTime DESC
```

And here is the error message:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that        corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'atmp
group by HourTime DESC' at line 12
```

Can anyone see it where my error is? I appreciate it. This is alos part of a lager program hence the java tag.

Comment: Why is this tagged as "Java"!? This is pure SQL...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`GROUP BY` doesn't have an order. You need to sort with `ORDER BY`.

```
GROUP BY HourTime 
ORDER BY HourTime DESC
```

Comment: Thanks, I needed to also remove `atmp` as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you mean is:

```
...
group by HourTime
order by HourTime desc
```